# If two cells match return third

Tags: excel, match

Struggling with the following

Sheet 1 column A - a List of SKU's
Sheet 2 column D - a list of the same SKU's
Sheet 1 column D - a list of associated barcodes

The SKU's in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are in different orders and some are missing from Sheet 1, that are present in sheet 2.

For the life of me I can't find a formula that will search sheet 1 column A, find it and match it in sheet 2 column D and retrieve the associated barcode in sheet 1 column D and show it in sheet 2 column G

Comment: Check out / give `Vlookup()` a try...

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet 2, Column G, enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(Sheet2!D1,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```